# prove that $f(z)+f(iz)=0$ please

Tags: complex-numbers

When

## $f(z).f(iz)=z^2\space \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$

## How to prove that

## $f(z)+f(iz)=0     \        \   \space \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$

I try
Let  $f(z)+f(iz)=M$

$ f(z)=\frac {z^2}{f(iz)}$

$M=\frac {z^2}{f(z)}+f(z).....(1)$

$M=\frac {z^2}{f(iz)}+f(iz)......(2)$

How complet that Or another method to prove that

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that your dot notation in $f(z).f(iz)$ actually means the usual multiplication in $\Bbb{C}$

**Counter-example.** The conclusion of the problem is actually false even when we focus only on entire functions. Indeed, if $f$ is entire such that

$$ f(z)f(iz) = z^2 \quad \text{and} \quad f(z) + f(iz) = 0 \quad \forall z \in \Bbb{C},$$

then we must have

$$ f(z) \in \{ iz, -iz \} \quad \forall z \in \Bbb{C}. $$

Then either the set $\{z : f(z) = iz \}$ or the set $\{z : f(z) = -iz\}$ is uncountable, and in particular, has accumulation points. By the identity theorem, this forces either $f(z) = iz$ or $f(z) = -iz$. But neither solves $f(z)f(iz) = z^2$, hence there is no such entire function.

There are bunch of entire functions that solve $f(z)f(iz) = z^2$, however. For example, if $g(z)$ is any entire function such that $g(z)g(iz) = 1$, then

$$ f(z) = e^{-i\pi/4}z g(z) $$

solves the functional equation. An obvious choice for $g$ is $g(z) = 1$, but there are other choices such as $g(z) = e^{z^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have $f(z).f(iz)=z^2$.

Now if you look at $f(iz)$ you have $f(iz)f(i(iz))=f(iz)f(-z)=(iz)^2=-z^2$. So for $f(iz)\neq0$,  $f(z) + f(-z) = z^2/f(iz) - z^2/f(iz) = 0$

Finally, if $f(iz)=0$ then $z^2 = 0$ and so $z=0$. Hence $f(0)f(i0)=f(0)f(0)=0$, so $f(0)=0$ and we are done.

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose that $f(z)+f(iz)=0, \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$, then, the hyphotesis becomes: $f^2(z)=-z^2$ or $f^2(z)-(iz)^2=0$, or $(f(z)-iz)(f(z)+iz)=0, \forall z\in \mathbb{C}$, and so $f(z) \in \{ -iz,iz \}, \forall z\in \mathbb{C}$. Now, if there is an $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=iz$, then, because $f(iz)\in \{ i \cdot iz,-i \cdot iz \}$, we have that $f(z)f(iz) \in \{ -iz^2,iz^2 \}$. But, $f(z)f(iz)=z^2$, so $z=0$. So, $f(z)=-iz, \forall z\in \mathbb{C}^*$. Then, for instance, $f(1)=-i$, and $f(i)=-i^2=1$, and so $f(1)f(i)=(-i) \cdot 1=-i \neq 1$ (F).
So, probably, as user96233 proved, the conclusion must be $f(z)+f(-z)=0, \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$.