# A function such that $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ such that $f(z)f(iz)=z^2$ satisfies $f(z)+f(-z)=0$.(MADHAVA-2020)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, problem-solving

Suppose $f$ is a function such that $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ such that $f(z)f(iz)=z^2$, then we have to show that $\forall z\in \mathbb C f(z)+f(-z)=0 $.

Actually I have solved this problem and have no doubt about it but actually this question came in MADHAVA-2020. So I posted it on this site.

I am not answering the question and inviting all users to answer it. 
It is a nice problem.

I will answer it within a week, but I am letting everyone try.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1292528

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all it is trivial to check that the equation is satisfied trivially for $z=0$ since from the functional equation we have $$f(0)f(0)=0\implies f(0)=0$$

Now use $z\mapsto iz$ in the functional equation to get $$f(iz)f(-z)=-z^2$$ Adding this to the original equation we get $$\displaystyle f(iz)(f(z)+f(-z))=0$$

So either $f(iz)=0$ (which trivially gives that $f(z)=0$, $\forall$ $ z\in  
 $ $\mathbb{C}$ and hence the result will be proved) or $\displaystyle f(z)+f(-z)=0$.

So in either case the last equality holds $\forall$ $z\in\Bbb{C}$

Answer (score 3):

For $z=0$, we get $f(0)f(0)=0$ and so the claim holds for $z=0$.
On the other hand, for $z\ne 0$, we necessarily have $f(z)\ne0$ (and $f(iz)\ne0$).
From
$$f(z)f(iz)=z^2$$
we get 
$$f(iz)f(-z) = f(iz)f(i^2z)=(iz)^2=-z^2,$$
so that 
$$ (f(z)+f(-z))f(iz) = z^2-z^2=0.$$
As $f(iz)\ne0$, the claim follows.

Comment: You just beat me by 6 seconds!!!!!